# Cannot display record to DataGridView in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This is what my table "Item" look like in my database:
[image]

Now, I want to display it inside my winforms application. My application include the main page that look like this: [image]

When I click the Store button, I expect the program will access the DataGridView inside UserControl1 that I have created and input all id, name and price from my database into it.
This is how I make it inside the main view page:

```
string connectionString = @"myconnectionString";     
private void storeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        userControl21.Hide();
        userControl11.Show();
        userControl11.BringToFront();
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlData = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM \"Item\"", sqlCon);
            DataTable mytable = new DataTable();
            sqlData.Fill(mytable);

            UserControl1 uctl1 = new UserControl1();
            uctl1.storeGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            uctl1.storeGridView.DataSource = mytable;

        }
    }
```

I already also putting DataPropertyName inside my UserControl DataGridView the same name with the column i want to get record in my database. And when I run program, everything run and there's no bug occured, but when I click the "Store" button, nothing come out, there's no record displayed.
I also try to debug step by step but still have no idea why it doesn't received any record. At this rate, I would really appreciate any help coming.

Comment: You have created a new instance of `UserControl1` (bad name), but this UC is never added to any Container. Did you mean to use an existing instance of this UC instead? -- Not clear what `userControl21` (bad name) and `userControl11` (bad name) have to do with this. -- Check your query, too.

Comment: @Jimi what you mean by added to Container tho ? Can do tell me how to do it?

Comment: Well, when you create the instance of a Control or UserControl and you want to show it in a Form/Window, you have to add it to a Container. The Container can be the Form, a Panel, a TableLayoutPanel, a ToolStrip etc. For example, `this.Controls.Add(new UserControl1());` adds a new instance of an UC to a Form. -- BUT, it looks like you already have a DataGridView that may be named `storeGridView`, possibly child of an UserControl that is already added to a Form, in the Designer. So you probably want to set the DataSource of that already existing DGV child of an already existing UC.

Comment: This: `UserControl1 uctl1 = new UserControl1();` creates a new instance of `UserControl1` - unrelated to any existing instance of this UC - which you never show, since you never add it to a Container.

Comment: @Jimi I do already created `DataGridView` named `storeGridView` inside a UserControl. But how I can call it into my form ? I tried something like `storeGridView.Datasource = mytable` but then I got the error `The name 'storeGridView' does not exist in the current context` . So I tried something else like `UserControl1.storeGridView.DataSource = mytable;` but I got another error `An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'UserControl1.storeGridView'`. The only way that doesn't yell error is as in my question.

Comment: Add a public Method to the UserControl you have created. Could be `public void SetDataSource(DataTable dt) { storeGridView.DataSource = null; storeGridView.DataSource = dt; }`. Call that method using the existing instance of `UserControl1` and pass the DataTable you have just filled.

Comment: @Jimi it's finally works, thank you a lot for your help. I was frustrated so much.